# Java concurrency, stream behavior

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java.util.concurrent

Methods `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` of this class is invoked concurrently. It is a part of a web app.

Internal maps populated as well with no concurrency.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Map<String, List<List<String>>> first;

    private Map<String, List<List<String>>> second;

    public MyClass() {
        first = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        second = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public Set<String> getFirst(String key, String token, int a, int b) {
        return get(first, key, token, a, b);
    }

    public Set<String> getSecond(String key, String token, int a, int b) {
        return get(second, key, token, a, b);
    }

    private Set<String> get(final Map<String, List<List<String>>> map, final String key, final String token,
        final int a, final int b) {
        Set<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
        map.get(key).stream().filter(i -> i.size() <= b && i.size() >= a).forEach(
            s -> result
                .addAll(s.stream().filter(p -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(p, token)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        return result;
    }
}
```

I tested it with something like `ab -n 10000 -c 100` (Apache's utility). And I log it. I get the same set all times. But if I change `map.get(key).stream()` to `map.get(key).parallelStream()` and do the same steps I get sometimes different result size (always smaller).

What is it?

Comment: Try using a thread-safe set to collect your results.

Comment: Thread safe version of Set?

Comment: @SDmitry: why not? `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Boolean>())`

Comment: @SDmitry [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html)?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon @TagirValeev By using a thread-safe Collection or Map, you add another problem: contention due to synchronized locking. In a high performance system, you want to avoid that at all cost. Better to use thread-safe stream operations on non-thread-safe collections. Some collectors defined in `Collectors.*` and used in `stream.collect(...)` provide smart ways of providing thread safety without contention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `TreeSet.addAll()` inside the `forEach` of parallel stream. The `forEach` body can be executed simultaneously several times in different threads for different elements and [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is not thread-safe. To fix the problem quickly you can either synchronize modification of `result` or use [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-). However it would be cleaner and more performant to [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) your stream and collect it at once without `forEach`. Try this version:

```
return map.get(key).stream()
        .filter(i -> i.size() <= b && i.size() >= a)
        .flatMap(List::stream).filter(p -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(p, token))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```